# Termination resistors for RAM vs drive strength

Tags: ram, signal-integrity

I'm considering using a RAM IC (S27K HyperRAM from Cypress).

The layout guidelines document suggests adding series resistors "if necessary."

However, the datasheet for the device has a register where you can set the "Drive Strength." The registers allow for a wide variety of values: 19, 22, 27, 34, 46, 67, 115 Ohms.

Does the "Drive Strength" (output impedance) work similar to adding a series resistor for signal integrity purposes? Does this mean I could skip the series resistor and just program the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That setting sets the output impedance of the driver. So it basically behaves as a configurable, internal, source series termination resistor so that you don't need to use an external one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was only thinking from the perspective of using the source resistance (termination) to manage reflections. So from the two perspectives (reflections and edge speed), would there be any difference between, say, a 20 Ohm drive-strength + 30 Ohm series resistor, versus a 30 Ohm drive strength + 20 Ohm series resistor?

Comment: @sgdsgyhetwaraw It depends on whether the label "20 Ohm drive-strength" means the drive strength to be used with 20 Ohms, or whether it changes the driver impedance to 20Ohms. I am not sure which convention is used.

Comment: From skimming, it looks the label means the driver output impedance. So the answer to your question would be no. Which makes my answer somewhat erroneous since the setting ends up just being a configurable, internal series source termination resistor.

Comment: I will still probably put some series resistors just in case because they are so small and inexpensive, but this helps my understanding and confidence. I'm also speculating, but maybe under certain conditions the mismatch could be large enough to cause issues witch the initial communications for changing the default drive-strength to the optimal one.